# debugger version of flash not loading swf unless user mouseover

Tags: flash, debugging, datefield, datechooser

I have embedded the calender (datefield and datechooser) control of flex in cfm. When my application page loads the calender (swf) gets loads only if we mouseover the placeholder. However the issue is only in machines which have the debugger flash version and works fine in release version.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Some of your code would be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot weltraumpirat for the response.

The problem has been solved. It was because I had set the dimensions of the placeholder in % value.

I had given the height and width my container (span) in percentage which I have now hard coded .And then in the event handler of the the calender pop-up i set the calendar dimensions to 100% which would always show it perfectly.

Thanks all.